# Use OAuth2 with Spring Security OAuth2 and reactor netty in a webflux project without servlet api

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I want to use webflux with reactor netty,but my project that relies on spring-security-oauth2 , specifically with the class https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2Authentication.java, to work with oauth2, but this project use the servlet api, and netty does not support the servlet api. It's possible to use reactor netty with the spring-security-oauth2 project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `spring-security-oauth2` has been lifted into Spring security 5 and is no longer a standalone library.

Spring security 5 also has support for webflux.

[Webflux security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#reactive-applications)

Comment: Hi @thomas, I've seen their [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security) about it,   and the [faq](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security)  but the sample that they [provide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.0.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2login)  relies on [spring-security-oauth2-client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.2.0.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2login/spring-security-samples-boot-oauth2login.gradle#L5).

Comment: security-oauth2-client has a dependency with the servlet api, as you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/spring-security-oauth2-client.gradle#L23) . In my case, I don't want to use tomcat, jetty or undertow, which provides the servlet api, but I want to use reactor netty, which is not a servlet container, with webflux.

Comment: I think you have gotten somethings wrong. Just because you have a dependecy on the servlet api doesn’t automatically mean you are running tomcat/jetty or undertow. Webflux does not att all work with anything but netty. So as soon as you choose webflux you are automatically given netty as the underlying implementation. The servlet api is just a set of interfaces.

Comment: I know that doesn’t automatically mean that I need tomcat or other servlet container, but as you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1) , the servlet-api need to be provided at runtime by a servlet container. Even if a just add this dependency to my netty project, the project will not able to run because the dependency need to be provided by a servlet container, in this case tomcat, jetty or undertow. If you think there is another option, please let me know.

Comment: You dont add that dependency, all the classes you need is included in the spring security library. That library is deprecated.